# Why there are 8 zeros before digit 1 [ 0.000000001 ETH]

Tags: ether

Unable to understand why Block chain uses before decimal point uses 8 zeros. As far as ETH its Giga Wei and satoshi for bitcoin. But why we use so many zeros?

Comment: Without context of you telling where did you obtain this number, it is impossible to tell why your particular number has eight zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Representing floating point numbers and doing float arithmetic in code is funky. We prefer to use integers (in solidity's case, unsigned 256 bit integers, `uint256`).

As such, 1 unit of value in Ethereum (for example, `msg.value==1` in the context of a transaction) in reality represents the smallest amount of Ethereum available for calculation: 1 wei, or `10^(-18)` Ethers.

To help with arithmetic, solidity also employs helpers as global variables, such as:

```
msg.value = 1 wei; //This is 1:1 with what I just described
msg.value = 2 gwei //This is equivalent to 2 * 1e9 weis
msg.value = 3 ether // This is equivalent to 3 * 1e18 weis, 3 full ethers
```

You can read up more on it, as well as the philosophy behind it, in the solidity docs here:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/units-and-global-variables.html